# Constraining returned object properties based on passed string parameter

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I want implement a function `pluck` which returns `key:value` object

```js
function pluck<T>(source:T,key:keyof T):Record<typeof key , T[typeof key]>{
    return {[key]:source[key]}
}
```

but returned type contains all keys of passed `source` not just `key` on type definition.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your primary problem is that the type of `key` is all of `keyof T`, where it should be a generic type that *extends* `keyof T` so it can be inferred as *one* of the keys in `keyof T`.  That means:

```
function pluck<T, K extends keyof T>(source: T, key: K): Record<K, T[K]> {
  return { [key]: source[key] } as Record<K, T[K]>; // see footnote*
}
```

This should work for you.  Note that the type `Record<K, T[K]>` can be written more tersely as `Pick<T, K>`:

```
function pluck<T, K extends keyof T>(source: T, key: K): Pick<T,K> {
  return { [key]: source[key] } as Pick<T,K>; // see footnote*
}
```

Hope that helps; good luck!

<sub>* Note that you need to assert the type of the return value, due to a [TypeScript bug](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14473) which (despite being closed) might not be completely resolved.</sub>